# How to solve the Run-tine error '1004' application-define or object-defined for my VBA code

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to Write a code that nested sort my mutual Fund and etf information base on different the number of different property that refers to the value of different column.

```
Sub SortSections()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim mutualFundRange As Range
    Dim etfRange As Range
    Dim MFF As String
    Dim MFAD As String
    Dim ETFF As String
    Dim ETFAD As String
    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long
    
    Dim RowCount As Long
    Dim RowCountL As Long
    ' Set the worksheet where your data is located
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1") ' Replace "Sheet1" with your sheet name
    
    ' Define the ranges for each section
    RowCount = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    RowCountL = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "L").End(xlUp).Row
    Set mutualFundRange = ws.Range("B" & RowCount).CurrentRegion
    Set etfRange = ws.Range("L" & RowCountL).CurrentRegion
    
    ' Get the values for sorting criteria
    MFF = ws.Range("H4").Value
    MFAD = ws.Range("I4").Value
    ETFF = ws.Range("L4").Value
    ETFAD = ws.Range("M4").Value
    
    ' Sort each section based on different criteria and sorting orders
    For i = 1 To 5
        MFF = ws.Cells(i + 3, "H").Value
        MFAD = ws.Cells(i + 3, "I").Value
        ETFF = ws.Cells(i + 3, "L").Value
        ETFAD = ws.Cells(i + 3, "M").Value
        For j = 2 To mutualFundRange.Columns.Count
            If MFF = mutualFundRange.Cells(1, j).Value Then
                If MFAD = "Asc" Then
                    mutualFundRange.Worksheet.Sort.SortFields.Add2 Key:=mutualFundRange.Columns(j), Order:=xlAscending
            **///This line abobe is the Run-tine error '1004'application-define or object-defined error and I   believe some lines down there also have issue**
                ElseIf MFAD = "Dec" Then
                    mutualFundRange.Worksheet.Sort.SortFields.Add2 Key:=mutualFundRange.Columns(j), Order:=xlDescending
                End If
            End If
        Next j
        For j = 2 To etfRange.Columns.Count
            If ETFF = etfRange.Cells(1, j).Value Then
                If ETFAD = "Asc" Then
                    etfRange.Worksheet.Sort.SortFields.Add2 Key:=mutualFundRange.Columns(j), Order:=xlAscending
                ElseIf ETFAD = "Dec" Then
                    etfRange.Worksheet.Sort.SortFields.Add2 Key:=mutualFundRange.Columns(j), Order:=xlDescending
                End If
            End If
        Next j
        SortRange mutualFundRange
        SortRange etfRange
    Next i
    
End Sub

Sub SortRange(ByRef rng As Range)
    With Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort
        .SetRange rng
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    End With
End Sub
```

I have never learned VBA before, so I kinda messed my code up a bit.

I try to just use sort function to sort on element only and it works out find, but I want to sort by multiple elements like custom sort.

What should I do?

Comment: The title of your question and the content of your question don't match ... please clarify what your question is. If you have a specific error (eg 1004) then please confirm on which line the error happens (will be highlighted in the VBE when you press 'Debug' in the error dialog)

Answer (score 0):

Provided code demonstrates how to sort two ranges. You need to apply serveral changes on your code.

- Clear all SortFields before apply new sorting
- Adding `SortFields` with `ActiveSheet.Sort.SortFields.Add2` instead of `mutualFundRange.Worksheet.Sort.SortFields.Add2`
- Adding `.Apply` in `SortRange()`

```vb
Sub demo()
    Dim dRng1 As Range, dRng2 As Range
    Set dRng1 = Range("A1:E7")
    dRng1.Select
    ActiveSheet.Sort.SortFields.Clear
    For c = 1 To dRng1.Columns.Count
        ActiveSheet.Sort.SortFields.Add2 Key:=dRng1.Columns(c) _
            , SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlDescending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    Next
    SortRange dRng1
    ActiveSheet.Sort.SortFields.Clear
    Set dRng2 = Range("G1:K7")
    For c = 1 To dRng2.Columns.Count
        ActiveSheet.Sort.SortFields.Add2 Key:=dRng2.Columns(c) _
            , SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    Next
    SortRange dRng2
End Sub

Sub SortRange(ByRef rng As Range)
    With ActiveSheet.Sort
        .SetRange rng
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .Apply
    End With
End Sub
```

[image]